# How to split data of single column to separate columns in pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using a csv file with dataframe name `content`. I am trying this code but it not providing expected output

```
new_content1 = content['Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5','Value6']
def get_pairs(x):
    arr = x.split(' ')
    return list(map(list, zip(arr, arr[1:])))

new_content1['pairs'] = new_content1.applymap(get_pairs)
new_content1
```

Value1 Value2 ....                  pairs(single column)
0   3     2    2 4 2 2      [[3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 2], [2, 2]]
1   1     2    3 4 5 6      [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can simply use:

```
new_content1['pairs'] = new_content1['ColName'].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

where ColName is column you want to split, it will return a values as list in `pairs` column

Alternatively, if you want the output to make new columns based on splits, e.g. two columns, you can use the above as:

```
new_content1[['newCol1', 'newCol2']] = new_content1['ColName'].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

As per your comment let say you have `df` column like this one:

```
Value
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

if your column are separate then join them using:

```
df['Value']=df['value1']+' '+df['value2']+' '+df['value3']+' '+df['value4']+' '+df['value5']+' '+df['value6']
```

then you can do this

```
df['Value']=df['Value'].astype('str')

df['new']=df['Value'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x:list((zip(x[:], x[1:]))))
```

Output looks like this

```
+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
| Value  |     new      |                pairs                     |
+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|     0  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
|     1  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
|     2  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
|     3  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
|     4  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
|     5  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
|     6  | 1 2 3 4 5 6  | [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)] |
+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple #error

Comment: can you share some of the data set

Comment: It’s a csv file with column value1 to value6 rows are like 2.5 million

Comment: just share some snippet, to get clear idea of how to you data is formatted

Comment: Value1   Value2 ....                                pairs(single column)
0    3              2               2 4 2 2         [[3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 2], [2, 2]]
1    1              2               3 4 5 6         [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]

Comment: @P_data Try to format expected part to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ nucsit026let me explain i have 6 columns value1, value2, value3 ,value4 ,value5 ,value6, in a dataframe(csv file) name content each one have numeric values and what i want to do is to make the pair of it like eg; 123456 is the values in each column then pairing should be made in separate column name Pairs [1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6] for each row in the dataframe.